# How to find intersections between line and rectangle with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to display a line "under" a rectangle. For this I tried using the intersections package, but somehow I the line doesn't stop:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% rectangle
\fill[name path=hrectangle, fill opacity=.5, rounded corners=1ex, shift={(-4cm,0cm)}, rotate=-30] ( -1,-.5) rectangle ( 1,.5);

% line
\draw[name path=x axis, <->, dashed] (7,0) -- (-4,0);

% intersection
\path[name intersections={of= x axis and hrectangle}];
\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
    \fill [color=red] (intersection-\i) circle (2pt) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get the error :

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known.
Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-2 is known.
```

Is there any other way I can do it?

Edit: The problem appears when I add the rounded corner of the rectangle...

Comment: Your axis is short. extend it to `-7` and it works on my computer with TikZ v.2.10

Comment: Or remove `shift={(-4cm,0cm)}`

Comment: Hum yeah the "rounded corners=1ex" make it not working...

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug. The intersections library should apply `\pgfprocessround` for both intersection paths. In fact, it does it for neither. I'm surprised this hasn't been noticed before, in particular by the author of `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex`.
`

Comment: @MarkWibrow At present, I guess this is an 'answer': could you make it one (or update us on a fix)?

Comment: @JosephWright It seems that TikZ processes the rounded corners before passing the path to PGF anyway, but it should have been done at the PGF level anyway, so was a bug and should be fixed now in the CVS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is fixed in the latest release of the package.

Comment: For me, things seem to work correctly with the latest `pgf` release. Other than 'update' there is therefore not much of an answer, so I've gone with the site convention and closed.